# Improve speed of very slow appending of files to master file

Tags: excel, ssis, etl

I am trying to combine (or perhaps append is a better term) a group (10) of identical column Excel files into one master file.

I have tried a very simple process using a foreach loop in the control flow and simply doing an Excel Source to an Excel Destination.  The process was not only slow (about 1 record pasted per second) but the process died after about 50k records.

It looks like:
Foreach Loop Container --> Data Flow task

where the Data Flow Task is Excel Source --> Excel Destination

At the end, I'd want to see one master file with all files appended.  I recognize there are other tools that can do this like PowerQuery directly in Excel, but I'm trying to better understand SSIS and I have a lot of processing that would be better done in SQL Server.

Is there a better way to do this?  I searched high and low online but couldn't find an example of this in SSIS.

Comment: Can you post an [mcve] of your code?

Comment: Embarrassed to ask but how would I export it?  I have only worked with the linking toolbox and edited via the properties windows.

Comment: I found the view code but its a huge xml file.  Is there a different export to view?

Comment: I would just write a macro and have it do that rather than relying on SSIS for such a need. SSIS in this case is overkill.

Comment: I have done what you suggest, I just wanted to test the ability to do in SSIS, as an Excel expert trying to learn SQL Server and related tools

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. The one thing I would suggest is to load to a flat file in csv format that easily opens in Excel.

1. Foreach Loop enumerated on filename.
2. In Foreach GUI set:
3. The path of the Excel files
4. The structure of the file (ex myfiles*.xls)
5. Go to Variable mapping and map the fully qualified name to a variable
6. Create an Excel connection to any one of the files.
7. In excel connection properties open Expression and set filepath to the variable from 5
8. Also in properties set delay validation to true
9. Add a dataflow task to the foreach loop container
10. goto dataflow
11. Use source assistant to read excel source
12. use destination assistant to load to a flat file (may sure not to overwrite destination or you will only get the last workbook